# No Route To Host from one VM on LAN

Tags: dns, routing, firewall

I'm quite stumped/frusterated as I can't get postfix to work on one of my VM's. It is a "template" VM and I have setup other VM's with this template fine. The only difference I can really think of is this VM's purpose which is ZoneMinder security software.

I tried using `telnet mail.domain.com 25` & `ssh root@mail.domain.com` and I get `No Route To Host` for both. Both of these work from other VM's inside the LAN and the `mail.domain.com` is also inside the LAN.

Here is the network config from the VM in question (which is Ubuntu 18 BTW):

```
root@sub:~# cat /etc/network/interfaces                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See                                                                                                                                                                                                       
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#    sudo apt install ifupdown                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        


# The loopback network interface                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
auto lo                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
iface lo inet loopback                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

# The primary network interface                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
auto ens3                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
#iface ens3 inet dhcp                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
iface ens3 inet static                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
address 192.168.1.255                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
netmask 255.255.255.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
gateway 192.168.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
dns-search domain.com
```

Here is the Hosts file:

```
root@sub:~# cat /etc/hosts                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
127.0.0.1       localhost sub.domain.com    sub                                                                                                                                                                                            
::1             localhost6 sub6.domain6.com sub6                                                                                                                                                                                           

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts                                                                                                                                                                                                            
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
fe00::0 ip6-localnet                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

And finally, I was able to SSH to other VM's in the LAN so I'm quite stumped. Any pointers or more information needed let me know.

Thank You

Update:

I am able to ping `mail.domain.com` from other VMs but not the one in question, I have never had this issue before.

Eg:

```
root@sub:~# ping mail.domain.com                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
PING mail.domain.com (192.168.1.237) 56(84) bytes of data.                                                                                                                                                                                               
From 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable                                                                                                                                                                                            
From 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable                                                                                                                                                                                            
From 192.168.1.255 (192.168.1.255) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Update2:

I have now removed the NIC from the VM and added a new one in case there was duplicate MAC issue.

I changed the IP address and the DNS entry in the gateway.

I rebooted the gateway after the above two steps still didn't work and I have been flushing the arp cache via `ip -s -s neigh flush all` periodically along w/ reboots just to make sure that isn't the issue.

Comment: `192.168.1.255` was your broadcast IP address. That's a conflict. You can't use the broadcast address as a computer address.

Comment: I was likely using that as an example, i don't know why, but sometimes I worry about sharing the real `private IPv4` address I use for services lol. @AlexisWilke You could make an edit if you want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% the issue (but it's fixed now!), but I found these two threads helpful.

[From 192.168.0.146 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371960/from-192-168-0-146-icmp-seq-1-destination-host-unreachable?rq=1)

[Host unreachable and I do not get why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35313/host-unreachable-and-i-do-not-get-why)

Basically it was one of two things:

- A duplicate IP address conflict
- A duplicate MAC address conflict

But, the trick was also to make sure to clear the arp cache via `ip -s -s neigh flush all` and/or reboot the VM/Target VM/Gateway Router.

I'm fairly certain my issue was a duplicate MAC address. I generally use disks as a template and create a new VM via the GUI and just point it to the copy of the disk template. But, I think this time I used a `domain.xml` and modified the `disk` parameter to point to the new disk. The issue was that `domain.xml` was still in use by the previous template VM w/ the same MAC.